# One fancybox window position on the top

Tags: search, fancybox, lightbox

Is there any chance to set position of Fancybox but only one window (to search). Beacase on page I am using Fancybox to show for example photos, map and windows for them and they are in the middle center of page, but I wanna just have this one - for searching on the top...

I have code:

`<a class="magnif fancybox-inline" href="#search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>`
`<div style="display:none" class="fancybox-hidden">`
 `<div class="searching" id="search">`
 `<form role="search" title="Searching" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo("url"); ?>">`
 `<div>`
 `<label class="screen-reader-text" for="s" hidden >Search</label>`
 `<input type="text" value="Write search fraze" name="s" id="s" onFocus="this.value='';" />`
 `</div>`
 `</form>`
 `</div>`
 `</div>`

Comment: What version are you using? Basically, add custom class name to the main element (using `mainClass` option for v3&4) and then use it to customize position. v3&4 uses CSS for vertical centering, but they have different techniques.

Comment: This is old version - 1.3.24 (2019/04/06).